# Disable system.out.println logs from Specific Java Package in catalina.out

Tags: java, logging, log4j, tomcat7

This may be an old question, but it did not work for me.

I am having an API which contains system.out.println. As it is from vendor I cannot comment that. So, I tried to disable from that specific java package. Below is the code I tried.

```
log4j.logger.com.backend.LogManager.class = OFF
```

I placed the above code in Myapp/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties. I also tried in Myapp/WEB_INF/ and Myapp/WEB-INF/lib/, but it did not work. I still see the API system.out.println logs in catalina.out file.

Also My lib directory contains log4j-1.2.14.jar and commons-logging-1.1.1.jar.

Please let me know how to prevent this as it is production environment, this causing issue in disk space.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the relation between `log4j.logger.com.backend.LogManager` and `System.out`.

Comment: Okay , So how to disable system.out logs in catalina.out?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you override `PrintStream` of `System.out` ?

I do a example to show that you can enable it and disable it if you store the original `PrintStream`.

If you also want to gain more time  you may override all println() method used by your API Vendor.

```
package sysout;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class DisableSysout {

    private static PrintStream outOriginal;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      outOriginal = System.out;
      doSysout();
      disableSysout();
      doSysout();
    }

    private static void doSysout() {
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for (int i=0;i<=500000;i++){
          System.out.println("Mess " + i);     
          System.out.println(i);
       }
      long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

      enableSysout();
      System.out.println("time="+ (end-start));
    }


    private static void enableSysout() {
      System.setOut(outOriginal);
    }

    private static void disableSysout() {

      System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        }

      }));
    }
}
```

Comment: As i said , it is an Vendor API . This should not be changed. I am looking for a configuration , so i can disable the system.out logs from specific java package

Comment: You don't need to change it. `System.out` is shared by all loaded classes by the JVM process. Besides, It's not possible to know the calling class of a `System.out`. That's why I propose you to disable and enable again the `sysout`.

Comment: I figured out the calling class by unpacking the API , so i can see the class and its package.